# Touch.salesforce.com + SSO + Mobile App setup for SSO

Tags: mobile, single-sign-on, app, ipad

I have done SSO using the federated way using ADFS and this is working fine on the desktop browser, my client has the requirement that if this is done then users should be able to login in to the following apps without using password:

- Touch.salesforce.com
- Salesforce Classic
- Salesforce for Outlook.

I am presently trying to do for the iPad using touch.salesforce.com:

Initially when I placed the SSO link in the safari browser it was redirecting me to touch.salesforce.com app, accidentally someone in the team clicked as to log out of this app and now when i place the SSO link it takes me to the normal browser version, can any one help me out with the following questions:

1. Can anyone help me getting the browser version of touch.salesforce.com when i use the SSO login in the safari browser - I reinstalled the App but even then the browser does not redirect me to the app.
2. When I click on the icon of touch.salesforce.com(app in iPad) it redirects me to the login screen, why does this happen ?
3. Should I always put the SSO link or enter the password, if this is the case then the whole idea of SSO is lost?

Can anyone help me out with this issue, the project is in the critical stage and i am stuck so is sfdc support.

Followed this Link:  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176614&language=en_US

No other docs are present in google.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

As of [Winter '14](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_mobile_touch.htm), touch.salesforce.com has been upgraded to Salesforce1.

To use Salesforce1 from your browser app, simply navigate to /one/one.app (but you may need to [spoof your user-agent](http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/)).